# How can you bind <B1-Motion> to a tkinter Button widget?

Tags: python, tkinter, bind

I'd like to use a Button widget to drag an item around.  If I'm using a Label widget, I can bind  to the widget and get the events, but Button widgets seem to consume all of the mouse events.  Any ideas?

Background:  I'm creating a grid where each row has several buttons to do various things.  I want to be able to reorder the rows by clicking on a drag-widget, then dragging the widget up and down (carrying the entire row with it).  Here's my GUI:

```
+---+--------------+---+---+
|        Title         | + |
+---+--------------+---+---+
| - | Label widget | = | > |
+---+--------------+---+---+
| - | Label widget | = | > |
+---+--------------+---+---+
| - | Label widget | = | > |
+---+--------------+---+---+
```

"+" is a button that adds a row (via a popup to fill in data), "-" is a button that removes the row, ">" is a button that lets you edit (via a popup) the row's data.  By clicking on and dragging "=", you can reorder the rows.  Currently, it's an image label, but I'd like it to be a button like the other controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Button widgets are no different than any other widget, except for the fact it already has bindings for some events (which means you need to either disable them, or be prepared to work with them). You can still bind any event you want to a button, though I question why you want to use a button for this purpose. Most people won't expect to be able to drag a button around -- button gives the affordance of being able to push it, not drag it.

If it were me, I'd rearrange your buttons to be this:

```
+---+--------------+---+---+
|        Title         | + |
+---+--------------+---+---+
| = | Label widget | > | - |
+---+--------------+---+---+
| = | Label widget | > | - |
+---+--------------+---+---+
| = | Label widget | > | - |
+---+--------------+---+---+
```

Then, change the "= button" to be an image that looks like something you can grab. Typically, I've seem images that have two or three horizontal lines as if to give "grip". Plus, I think it's more common to move something by grabbing an end than grabbing somewhere in the middle.

Now you can grab the left edge (which is arguably a more natural way to move things), and all of your add/delete buttons line up in the same column. Plus, the edit popup button is nestled right against the thing being edited, which to me makes sense.

You could also consider changing the layout to look like this:

```
+---+--------------+---+---+---+
|             Title            |
+---+--------------+---+---+---+
| = | Label widget | > | - | + |
+---+--------------+---+---+---+
| = | Label widget | > | - | + |
+---+--------------+---+---+---+
| = | Label widget | > | - | + |
+---+--------------+---+---+---+
```

The advantage to the above is that it lets you add a button in the middle rather than always adding or removing at the end, which means your users might learn to be able to add a row exactly where they want with one click rather than a click and a drag.

Comment: As I said, I wanted a Button since all the other stuff is Buttons.  Actually, for a while I played with using image Labels for everything, but replicating standard Button behavior was taking up too much of my time.  My layout is loosely based on the standard iOS apps, where the "+" is generally at the upper right (and being on a line by itself is handy when the list is empty), while the "-" is by itself on the left (presumably to reduce accidentally tapping).  And all of my button are using Tango icons, falling back to the characters if there's a problem.  Thanks for the feedback.